# atomic counter which can be disabled when reaches to 0

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

I want to implement the following atomic object which supports the following operations:

```
inc_and_get(X)              - increment the counter and return the previous value
dec(X)                      - decrement the counter
inc_and_disable_if_zero (x) - increment the counter, but if the value is zero, disable it
                              disable means it returns -1 for every operation
```

inc_and_get(X) and dec(X) can be implemented using basic hardware primitives

the one i am intrested in is:

```
inc_and_disable_if_zero
```

increment corresponds to entering a critical section and decrement to leaving.

a thread entering the critical section can decide to regularly enter (by doing inc_and_get) or try to enter and disable the counter if possible (no one else is there) by calling inc_and_disable_if_zero

I think it is possible to solve this with CAS(X):

```
inc_and_disable_if_zero(X)
do {
    value = READ(X)
    if (value == 0) {
        next_value = -1;
        disable = TRUE;

    } else if (value > 0) {
        next_value = value + 1; // no good, :( , just increment
        disable = FALSE;

    } else {
        return (TRUE); // someone else disabled it

    }
} while (!CAS(value, next_value));

return (disable);
```

But I was wondering if is there a more elegant way to solve this (with a single neat atomic 
operation) ?

for example, increment and set MSB if counter is zero ?

Answer (score 0):

JFYI: CAS have three arguments, pointer to atomic variable, old value and new value.

You can solve this problem with double checked locking (on spinlock):

```
int inc_and_disable_if_zero(Counter* X) {
    // fast path
    if (X->value == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    lock(X->spinlock);
    if (X->value == -1) {
        unlock(X->spinlock);
        return -1;
    }
    if (X->value == 0) {
        X->value = -1;
        unlock(X->spinlock);
        return -1;
    }
    X->value++;
    int res = X->value;
    unlock(X->spinlock);
    return res;
}
```

In this case all updates to counter must be performed under spinlock.

```
int inc(Counter* X) {
    // fast path
    if (X->value == -1) { return -1; } // this value couldn't change so
                                       // there is no need for synchronization
    lock(X->spinlock);
    if (X->value == -1) { return -1; }
    X->value++;
    int res = X->value;
    unlock(X->spinlock);
    return res;
}
```

Performance will be good in this case, spinlock lock/unlock is just a RMW operation, the same as CAS.

> for example, increment and set MSB if counter is zero ?

I beleve this is possible on modern Intel 'Haswell' processors using TSX(Transactional Synchronization Extensions). With regular CAS operation this is impossible, I believe.